# backbone "mouseleave" is fired when the "click" event is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

When the cursor leaves a div, the *mouseleave* event is fired, but if I click on a button inside the div, both the *mouseleave* and *click* events fire, although my cursor is still inside the div.

here is the code:

```
events: {
    'mouseleave': 'test_1',
    'click button': 'test_2'    
},

test_1: function() {
    alert('mouseleave!');
},

test_2: function() {
    alert('click!');
}
```

When I click the botton the *mouseleave* alert appears. Why??

Comment: Can you show some markup? however I assume what's happening is your script might think you're leaving the div when you hover over the mouse and click.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `alert` to `console.log`.  I think it's the alert in test_2 that is causing you to leave the div.